# AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. Swagger Consuming another API - .net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern

I am trying to consume a web service in my web api application and got the the error on the title while testing.  I checked my mapping and it looks ok.  I am trying to follow the Repository pattern. Below is my code:

The model:

```
 using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace AppleApi.Models
{
    public class ApplicantInfo
    {
        [Key]
        public int Ctr { get; set; }

        public int Case_ID { get; set; }

        public int Actor_ID { get; set; }

        public string Name1 { get; set; }

        public string Name3 { get; set; }

        public string Full_Name { get; set; }

        public string Full_Name_Original { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Zip_Code { get; set; }

        public string State_ID { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string State_ID { get; set; }

        public string Match { get; set; }

        public bool PartyChangedIndicator { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The code on the DTO

```
using System;
namespace AppleApi.Dto
{
    public class ApplicantInfoDto
    {

        public int Ctr { get; set; }

        public int Case_ID { get; set; }

        public int Actor_ID { get; set; }

        public string Name1 { get; set; }

        public string Name3 { get; set; }

        public string Full_Name { get; set; }

        public string Full_Name_Original { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Zip_Code { get; set; }

        public string State_ID { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Zip_Code { get; set; }

        public string State_ID { get; set; }

        public string Match { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The DB Context file:

```
        public DbSet<ApplicantInfo> ApplicantInfos { get; set; }
```

The Interface

```
using System;
using AppleApi.Models;

namespace AppleApi.Interfaces
{
    public interface IApplicantInfoRepository
    {
        Task<List<ApplicantInfo>> GetAllAsync();
        Task<ApplicantInfo> GetApplicantInfoAsync(string Number);
        Task<ApplicantInfo> CreateApplicantInfoAsync(ApplicantInfo ApplicantInfo);      
        
    }
}
```

and the Repository

```
    using System;
using AppleApi.Interfaces;
using AppleApi.Models;
using AutoMapper;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace AppleApi.Repository
{
    public class ApplicantRepository : IApplicantInfoRepository
    {

        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;


        public WipoApplicantRepository(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, HttpClient client)
        {
            this._configuration = configuration;
            this._env = webHostEnvironment;
            this._client = client;
        }

       

        

        public async Task<ApplicantInfo> GetApplicantInfoAsync(string Number)
        {
            string baseUrl = _configuration.GetSection("BaseAPI").GetSection("baseURL").Value;

            var httpResponse = await _client.GetAsync($"{baseUrl}{Number}");

            if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot retrieve tasks");
            }

            var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var ApplicantInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicantInfo>(content);

            return ApplicantInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

and lastly the Controller

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
using AppleApi.Dto;
using AppleApi.Interfaces;
using AAppleApi.Models;
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace AppleApi.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors(origins: "https://localhost:7059/", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class ApplicantInfoController : Controller
    {

        private readonly IApplicantInfoRepository _ApplicantInfoRepository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ApplicantInfoController(IApplicantInfoRepository ApplicantInfoRepository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            this._ApplicantInfoRepository =  ApplicantInfoRepository;
            this._mapper = mapper;
        }



        [HttpGet("{Number}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(ApplicantInfo))]
        [ProducesResponseType(400)]
        public IActionResult GetApplicantInfo(string Number)
        {



            

            var ApplicantInfo = _mapper.Map<ApplicantInfoDto>(_ApplicantInfoRepository.GetApplicantInfoAsync(Number));

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            return Ok(ApplicantInfo);
        }


    }
}
```

and the mapping profile codes is as shown below:

```
using System;
using AppleApi.Dto;
using AppleApi.Models;
using AutoMapper;

namespace AppleApi.Helper
{
    public class MappingProfiles : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfiles()
        {
            
            CreateMap<ApplicantInfo, ApplicantInfoDto>();
            CreateMap<ApplicantInfoDto, ApplicantInfo>();

        }

    }
}
```

This is my first .net application, I'll understand if I made some silly mistakes.

Comment: Can you provide the exception message that you get in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **GetApplicantInfoAsync** method in the repository response type is `Task<ApplicantInfo>`.
So you need invoke the method with `await` and also make sure **GetApplicantInfo** method `async Task<IActionResult>`:

```
[HttpGet("{Number}")]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(ApplicantInfo))]
[ProducesResponseType(400)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetApplicantInfo(string Number)
{
    var ApplicantInfo = _mapper.Map<ApplicantInfoDto>(await _ApplicantInfoRepository.GetApplicantInfoAsync(Number));

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return BadRequest(ModelState);

    return Ok(ApplicantInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've missed an `await`

```
_mapper.Map<ApplicantInfoDto>(await _ApplicantInfoRepository.GetApplicantInfoAsync(Number));
```

`exception.ToString()` has all the info you need to diagnose the issue.